# Enigmatic iptables behavior

Tags: iptables, proxy, nat, squid

I configured two virtual machines both running Debian Wheezy in order to use them as server and client systems within the same NAT network. They are both able to reach each other, as ping shows.

Today I configured a Squid proxy on the server, but neither accessing the proxy by PAM authentification nor accessing it by redirecting HTTP traffic to its port (after having configured Squid as a transparent proxy) worked, and even after I spent hours at checking and modifying the configuration I wasn't able to solve this issue.

However, the concrete question I'd like to ask here is rather related to a totally strange behavior of the iptable entry which should normally redirect the HTTP traffic to the Squid port - And although I also spent quite much time to search for this, I wasn't able to find anyone else who experiences this behavior.

The iptables command is quite easy to understand as I would say:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

The entry also shows up in the PREROUTING chain of the NAT table:

```
iptables -t nat -L -n -v
```

> Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 4249 bytes)  pkts bytes
>   target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> ```
> 0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 3128
> ```

Nonetheless this rule gets ignored, since traceroute doesn't show the NAT IP of my Squid proxy as the first hop, but the standard gateway (10.0.0.1). The Squid logs also show it's not receiving any requests.

I configured this as part of various Linux administration tasks, and several other people, who used the exactly same configuration on an identical virtual Debian Wheezy system (including the same NAT configuration of Virtual Box for the server and client systems) didn't encounter any problems with this at all. An experienced Linux system administrator wasn't able to find any explanation for this strange phenomenon as well.

I can reach websites, so I guess the PREROUTING chain simply gets ignored.

Since I really wonder what the reason for this behavior might be, I ran strace for the iptables commands, maybe there's something in the output which helps finding an explanation:

[strace iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128](http://pastebin.com/MRZusKAB)

[strace iptables -t nat -L -n -v](http://pastebin.com/XPMPfWmk)

I'd really appreciate it, if anyone has an idea what the reason for this odd behavior could be.

Thanks in advance

David

Comment: Are you sure the packet is coming from eth0 ? Add a log after the rule to see the log of your packet which is not catched by the redirect rule.

Comment: Dropped packages which appeared after tried <traceroute 172.217.22.46>: http://pastebin.com/29bnLuxm After having added the logging rules, traceroute was not able to resolve google.com anymore and <traceroute 172.217.22.46> resulted in the error message "send: operation not permitted" - Yes, the device is eth0

Comment: strace output for <traceroute 172.217.22.46>: http://pastebin.com/SRV0DdqE

Comment: could you try with 'echo "QUIT" | nc google.com 80'  ? Traceroute doesn't use the port 80 on TCP.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake indeed, but I also tested this with many proxy testing sites and the NAT iptable shows that no data gets redirected. Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/1YyiuTWp

Comment: Is it working cross your proxy or directely ? Check the iptables or the proxy logs.

Comment: Could you also add the output of :  iptables-save -c     ? It's much easier to get your configuration than iptables -L

Comment: It seems that it was due to the VirtualBox networking settings being configured wrong: Client and server were in the same NAT network when they were able to ping each other, but then I must have changed something by mistake so that the redirection didn't work.